# Xcode Unable to determine compile to use

Tags: xcode, osx-lion

I recently installed Xcode 4.2.1 and attempted to create a simple "HelloWorld" application in C++. When I went to build to application I received the following:

```
Unable to determine compiler to use - the abstract compiler specification is missing from this Xcode installation.
```

I've uninstalled and reinstalled with no success.

I haven't been able to find and resources on the internet to help me resolve this.

I'm running Lion (upgraded from Snow Leopard).

Comment: Are you creating the app using a project or just your code? I recall having an error like this one a long time ago. If you want to compile something using Xcode, you have to create a project (File>New Project) and then select the type of app you want to create.

Comment: I'm creating it using the project wizard (File > New Project).

Comment: What command are you using to uninstall Xcode? Thinking more about this, this is certainly something wrong with your installation.

Comment: sudo <Xcode>/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all

Comment: Darn ... I can only speculate now. Have you tried building other projects? Mmmm if you have an old project, can you build it? Check for your gcc, go to the terminal and type `which llvm-gcc-4.2` the path where your gcc is installed should appear. Other thing I'm thinking, are you the admin of the computer? Do you have full privileges? ... Sorry I can't specifically help, these are just speculations :S

Answer (score 0):

Just copy Developer Folder for Xcode 4.2.1 from another Mac Machine and run Xcode from copied developer folder(/Developer 4.2.1/Applications/Xcode).That will work perfectly.

Comment: Are you saying he should run Xcode 4.x? That will not work for most developers.